# How was the air in the movie After Earth Contaminated?

Tags: after-earth

I just watched the movie After Earth. The air on the planet Earth, one million year after Humanity left it is still Contaminated. But there are still a large variety of flora and fauna flourishing. There are green rain forests and sunlight which should be enough for photosynthesis to occur. There should be no deficiency of Oxygen. Then why does Kitai had to take the Oxygen Extracting fluid?